# How to save the string array in sdcard using text format?

Tags: android, byte, fileoutputstream

```
  String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };
        Log.d("list",TextUtils.join(",", values));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

              String a="hi  is";
                File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdcardfile.txt");
                try {
                    myFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    //byte[] anotherArray = new byte[values.length];
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    int count;
                    long total = 0;
                    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    while ((count = values.length) != -1) {

                        total += count;
                //  FileWriter fos = new FileWriter(myFile);
               //   BufferedWriter bis = new BufferedWriter(fos);
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                    //bis.close();
                    //fos.close();
                    output.close();
                    }
```

Here my values are stored in my sdcard in text format.but when i open the text file,it contains bytes.here the values are stored in byte.how to change the byte to string inside when i write the fileoutputstrem.I want to get the values in text file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write it as text, then don't use `DataOutputStream`. Streams (InputStream and OutputStream) are for reading and writing binary data, not text. If you want to write text, use a `Writer` instead of an `OutputStream`. For example:

```
String[] array = ...  // wherever you get this from;  

File file = new File("StringFile.txt");  
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));  

// Write each string in the array on a separate line  
for (String s : array) {  
    out.println(s);  
}  


out.close();
```

Don't forget to put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

in your application's manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Read file in byte array and convert it to String like below.

```
    byte[] array = new byte[1000]; // 1000 is just given u can change it accordingly
      String s= new String(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a SQLite database or a ContentProvider ?

You can use DataOutputStream.writeUTF() and DataInputStream.readUTF() instead as these methods put the length of the strings in the file and read back the right number of characters automatically.